# Get the number of runs in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a simple loop, which has a step of 5. How can I get the index of the iteration of the loop? I know that we can derive this index using division, but I need those indices in the loop.

For a simple loop like the following, I want to print the list:

```
for i in range(0, 20, 5):
    print(' ')

out =  [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Just initialize a counter outside the for loop and increment it every time in the loop. Is this all you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want `print([i for i in range(0, 20, 5)])`?

Comment: Append to an first empty list (use out) the index i every time you loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```py
out = []
for counter, idx in enumerate(range(0, 20, 5)):
    print(idx)
    out.append(counter)

print(out)
```

This outputs:

```py
0
5
10
15
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
for index,i in enumerate(range(0, 20, 5)):
    print(f'{i}')
    print(f'{index}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two methods:

1. standard:

```py
    c = []
    for i in range(0, 20, 5):
        c.append(len(c));
    print(c);
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

2. optimized:

```py
        a = list(range(0, 20, 5))
        print(a)
        [0, 5, 10, 15]
        b = [i for i in range(0, len(a))]
        print(b)
        [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Thank you